# The exact use of AbstractCollection

Tags: java, collections, iterator

Could anyone explain me the exact use of `AbstractCollection`?

Bruce Eckel's **Thinking in Java** says that:

> AbstractCollection provides a default implementation for a Collection.

So does this mean that it's supposed to be used when we want to override `Collection` methods?

Comment: *"So does this mean that it's supposed to be used when we want to override Collection methods?"* - No, but it will save you a lot of work

Comment: In the first place, do you have any gripes agaisnt the existing collection implementations in the JDK? They cover plenty of use cases already

Comment: It's used as a base for implementing a custom `Collection`. It provides simple (sometimes naive) implementations of many methods.

Comment: So basically if someone needs a custom type of Collection ( a modified linked list for example) AbstractCollection should be used?

Comment: Why would you want to rewrite isEmpty, contains, toArray, remove, containsAll, toString, etc. when Joshua Bloch did a fine job the first time around?

Comment: I'm trying to get a deeper understanding, not really changing anything .

Comment: Fair enough.  As you probably have seen with most base classes in the Java API, there is a strong adherence to the pattern of defining an interface, an abstract implementation of that interface and concrete implementations on top of the abstract implementation.

Comment: Well, no idea about your future plans but I just dug an old project of mine which didn't even rely on `Abstract*` collections since they are immutable; see [here](https://github.com/fge/abic). Of course, if you want reliable, heavily tested immutable collections, you're better off using Guava ;)